# Modificar usuario en app.config

Tags: c#, app.config

Tengo una dll donde se pasan usuario y contraseña a través del `app.config` al webservice y me gustaría ver como hacer esto para que en lugar de pasar un hardcode se pase una variable que después se pueda informar a la dll en tiempo de ejecución. ¿Sería esto posible? No soy muy experto en c# la verdad por eso me esta costando pero manejo dos posibles escenarios:

1. incluir una `key` que se pueda modificar en un futuro desde el programa
2. que el programa modifique directamente el valor de la etiqueta `wsse:username` y el de `password`

Pero no soy capaz de implementar ninguna de las dos opciones y hacerlas funcionar.

El `app.config` seria algo asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="XXXXXX" value="XXXXXXX" />
    <add key="XXXXX" value="xxxxxx" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="e3s-xxxx">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="e3sxxxx">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxxx:443/ctxweb/secured_ssl/xxxx_waste"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="e3s-xxxx"
        contract="E3S_XXXX.Ie3xxxx" name="e3s-xxxx" >
         <headers>
          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
              <wsse:Username>miusuario</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">miprueba</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
```

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: No se si lo sepas per los App.Config no funcionan desde una dll, es decir, necesitas que la aplicación que usa tu dll tenga configurado su app.config. La dll utiliza el app.config de la aplicación, no el que configuras en el proyecto de la dll.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema de cambiar el <wsse:Username> y <wsse:Password>. Le habras encontrado solucion o una idea de como darle solucion al tema? Te lo agradecere.

Comment: Revisar este enlace: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-change-appconfig-data

Answer (score 0):

Para tu primer escenario creo que podría ayudarte, en mi caso, tengo una key en el app.config que me indica a que servidor quiero conectarme:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="server_al_que_me_conecto" value="y"/>
</appSettings>
```

Esa key tiene diferentes valores y en mi DLL de conexión obtengo el valor de la key y ésta, en función del valor, se conecta contra un servidor u otro (es decir, que yo podría cambiar el valor de la key y cambiar a donde se está conectado el aplicativo en tiempo de ejecución).

Obtengo el valor de la key tal que así:

```
   string contra_quien_estoy_conectando = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("server_al_que_me_conecto")[0].ToString();
```

En tu caso, además, quieres cambiar el valor de la key del app.config en tiempo de ejecución y, aunque no es mi caso, buscando un poco he encontrado esto que quizás te valga para cambiar esos valores:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath); 
config.AppSettings.Settings["Key"].Value="Value";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Prueba con esta info y espero que te sea de ayuda.
Buena suerte !!

Comment: Gracias raBinn, esa parte creo que es la única que me se aunque no la he podido probar porque mi primer problema es hacer referencia a la key desde el propio app.config... Quiero decir, como hay referencia a la variable "usuario_para_conectar" desde la etiqueta <wsee:username>... he probado diferentes opciones pero ninguna me funciona, aunque ahora no tengo claro si es que no se lleva el valor o si como el usuario no debe llevar comillas ni nada similar porque si no no funciona, si ese es el problema. No se si me explico.

Comment: Quizás tengas que refrescar la información de configuración con un **ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");** después de la modificación.